Send file contents to RabbitMQ
Here is my code to send file content to queue:
$documentToSend = ['file' => file_get_contents($filePath)];
Queue calling:
Queue::pushRaw(json_encode($documentToSend), 'service-call');

Here is my queue handle:
public function handle(){
     
  try {
      $file = $this->data->file;
      Storage::disk()->put($fileToPath, $file, 'public');
   } catch (Exception $e) {
      Log::error($e);
   }

}

Getting nothing in error nor any data.
Can anyone guide me?

you can log the variables to know what you are dealing with..

Found the solution of this.
We need to convert file to binary and send it:
$sendBinaryFileContent = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath));

Binary file handle:
$binaryFile = str_replace('data:application/pdf;base64,', '', $binaryFile); 
$file = base64_decode($binaryFile);

